# Problem in installing chatterbot in python 3.9

Tags: virtual-environment, chatterbot, python-3.9

I tried downloading the chatterbot package in windows 10 but it always shows an error.
I am using python 3.9 and trying to install it in a virtual environment.

I had recently downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 and I think that the error is caused by the build tools for C++  as I can see it in one of the lines below

These are my commands:

```
(virtual_assistant) C:\Users\DELL\my_envs>pip install chatterbot
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (2020.4)
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.2.19.tar.gz (5.7 MB)
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2
  Using cached nltk-3.5.zip (1.4 MB)
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3
  Using cached pymongo-3.11.0.tar.gz (771 kB)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  **Installing build dependencies ... error**
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-polm76zg\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (79 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (287 kB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.19.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.0 MB)
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.51.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for preshed, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for thinc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-380d1mym\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-380d1mym\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-sl91g3ci\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-polm76zg\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-polm76zg\overlay\include\site\python3.9\preshed'
           cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-380d1mym\preshed\
      Complete output (41 lines):
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
      copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
      running build_ext
      building 'preshed.maps' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -Ic:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\include -IC:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tppreshed/maps.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed/maps.obj /Ox /EHsc
      maps.cpp
      preshed/maps.cpp(5728): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5740): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5749): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5755): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5761): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(5767): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      preshed/maps.cpp(6129): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
      preshed/maps.cpp(6145): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
```

THIS IS THE LINE I MENTIONED ABOVE

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

```
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-380d1mym\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-380d1mym\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-sl91g3ci\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-polm76zg\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-polm76zg\overlay\include\site\python3.9\preshed' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\dell\my_envs\virtual_assistant\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-polm76zg\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9 is a new version of python as of now (November 2020), not all wheels are packaged for it yet.

Try using python 3.7 which has wheels available. If you must use a later version, you will need to [install from the source code](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html#installing-from-source).